# I have some tables in my page and on taking print it shows scroll on right side and not supporting page print on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, tabular

Html Page that I have is this picture:

[image]

Print preview that I'm getting:

[image]

How I can enable my print to flow on multiple pages.
and elso without scroll?

Please look on the images for the page view and the problem I have.
Actually my prints are not going to next page and shows scroll on the print.

CSS I've used is:

```
<style>
    @media print
    {
        @page
        { margin: 2% };
        table { page-break-inside:auto };
        tr { page-break-inside:auto; page-break-after:auto };
        thead { display: table-header-group };
        tbody { display: table-row-group };
    };
</style>
```

Please help.

Comment: Have to take actual print using Printer?

Comment: Somewhere there is overflow-y set for scroll? Turn that off in print css